# Initialize a Canvas variable with existing one

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to implement Undo-Redo operations on my Canvas in Silverlight 5. For this I want to save the canvas after each operation into a Stack, and on undo or redo operation, I want to replace the existing canvas with the one in the stack.

Problem faced is, when I equate the current canvas with a temp variable, a new copy is not made but both the canvas variables refer to the same canvas, i.e. changes done in one reflect on other. This creates problem when I change the current canvas and then undo to replace by temp canvas(which was equated to current canvas before the operation was performed), the temp canvas also gets the change that was done on the previous canvas(i.e. current canvas).

How can I make separate copies the canvas?? Please help.

I am initializing as below:

```
Canvas temp = new Canvas();
temp = currentCanvas;
```

Comment: You should not save the Canvas. Instead you should save the *state* of the Canvas, which would require to create an abstract representation of that state. Thus you would also get a separation of your application into model and view.

Answer (score 1):

In the full .Net framework, you can create a clone using the XamlReader and -Writer :

```
    public Canvas Clone(Canvas source)
    {
        var savedObj = XamlWriter.Save(source);
        var reader = new StringReader(savedObj);
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
        var canvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        return canvas;
    }
```

Edit:
Since silverlight does not support the XamlWriter and Reader, you can use [this generic class by Jim McCurdy](http://yinyangme.com/blog/post/Generic-class-for-deep-clone-of-Silverlight-and-C-objects.aspx) to clone a sliverlight object like this:

```
CloneObject.DeepClone<Canvas>(source,true);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please specify the libraries required too.

Comment: Just reference the `System.Windows.Markup` dll.

Comment: `XamlWriter` and `XamlReader.Create` are still not recognized. Help!!

Comment: You need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Markup`. Here is an explanation of how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I am not able to find System.Windows.Markup.dll in the references, but when I added this `using System.Windows.Markup;` to my code, `XamlReader.Load` is being recognized, but the rest of the two functions mentioned above are still not recognized. Do I need to download the dll or I am missing something else?

Comment: Ah you might also have to add the `System.Xaml` reference as well

Comment: Still not working.....here is something I found and it looks like silverlight do not support XamlWriter.... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.markup(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: You are right: Silverlight does not support this. I updated the answer for Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks, but still with this edit, the new temp canvas being created does not have the children present in the source canvas. I need the temp canvas to have the children too. Any suggestion!!!